# Is the question_id monotonically increasing?

Tags: support, api, stackapps

Just wondering:

- Does the question_id monotonically increase for every new question?
- Is the question_id unique globally for a deployed app or is it unique in some sub-domain?
- Is there any relation between a question_id and the tags which are associated with the question?
- Any correlatation to any other fields related to the question?

Comment: Chacha has it on the nose.  You really shouldn't rely on this information though, as it falls firmly under the 'implementation detail' heading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically:

Questions and Answers both use the same ID count. This means that the first question on a site would be ID 1. Then, the first answer is ID 2 and the second is ID 3. Then the next question on the site is ID 4. This keeps going.

This means that if you take the most recent post (question or answer), the ID will be the number of answers and questions that have ever been posted to the site. (Including deleted)

Comment: So, in answer to the latter three points, no.

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys. How about comments? Do they use the same ID count?

Comment: @Alienfluid - comments are on a different index, so no.  But once again, I wouldn't rely on that behavior.