# Retrieving a post with a specific ID

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, api

According to [this question (and its answer)](https://stackapps.com/questions/299), questions and answers are using the same index to determine their ID.  In other words:

- Question with ID #1

  - Answer with ID #2
  - Answer with ID #3
  - Answer with ID #4
- Question with ID #5

Because the 3 answers consumed 3 ids, it is impossible for a question to have ID #2, #3, or #4.  This is the behavior as defined in the question linked to above.

However, this is not reflected in the API.  In some cases, you must know the type of a post in order to request information about it.  For example, if you want to request the comments of a particular post, you must use either `/questions/{id}/comments` or `/answers/{id}/comments`.  It would be really wonderful if I could just use `/posts/{id}/comments` and not have to rely on knowing the post type in order to retrieve its comments.

Pretty please?

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: @Kevin it makes library implementation slightly simpler.  Specific example: retrieve the comments to a particular post.  Instead of having to know that the post is a Q or an A, I could just request `/posts/{id}/comments` and be done with it.  (which I realize now isn't immediately obvious in my question.  i'll update it)

Comment: There's some merit to a `posts/{id}/comments` method.  However, if any method might return **different** types (for instance, a hypothetical `/posts/{id}`) I'd have to say its not worth complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`/posts/{id}/comments`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/posts/1/comments?help) method has been implemented.